# Domain of $y'=\frac{1}{3y^2} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Differential equation :
$y'=\frac{1}{3y^2} $

This equation with the initial condition $y(x_0)=y_0$ exists the Existence and Unity theorem.

Find the domain of the solution when :

$(a) \space y(0)=3$

$(b) \space y(0)=-3$

$y'=\frac{1}{3y^2} \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{3y^2} \implies 3y^2dy=dx \implies \int 3y^2dy=\int dx \implies y^3=x+C$

$(a)\space 3^3=27=C \implies y^3=x+27$

$(b)\space -3^3=-27=C \implies y^3=x-27$

The domain of both is $-\infty<x<\infty.$

Is my solution correct?

Thank you!

Comment: The question is ill-posed. You cannot "find" the domain of a function, since the domain is what defines the function. When you solve a differential equation, you need to specify on what domain the equation is true. In this case, it seems that you want the equation to be true on an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ where $y\neq0$. As such, $$3y^2y'=1\implies{(y^3)'=1}\implies\int_{x_0}^x(y^3)'\,\mathrm{d}t=\int_{x_0}^x\,\mathrm{d}t\implies{y(x)^3-y(x_0)^3=x-x_0}\implies{y(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+y(x_0)^3-x_0}}$$

Comment: The above answer is the graph of a solution of the equation on any open interval domain $I$ such that $x_0-y(x_0)^3\notin{I}$. The reason for that is because if $x_0-y(x_0)^3\in{I}$, then $y$ is not differentiable at that point, so there is no function that satisfies the equation everywhere. Anyway, the point is that you need to specify an $I$ in which you want the equation to be true, in order for it to make sense to talk about whether a function is a solution or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It is wrong. Because the given ODE $y'=\frac1{3y^2}$ implies $y$ is non-zero.

So the first case, $x\ne-27$, and the second case, $x\ne27$.

Domain of the solution is often represented by interval, so the domain is...

a) $(-27,\infty)$. b) $(-\infty,27)$.